# CollectionView issue after scrolling to first item

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view and it automatically scrolls cells 1 by 1 to the end. And at the last cell i have a button to start over and scrolls to the first cell. Now everything works fine until this point but after scrolling to the first cell, i see my start over button (which is my last cell) on 3rd, 6th, 9th cells(basically 1 time for every 3 cells). HERE IS MY CODE:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return alpImageArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if (indexPath.item >= alpImageArray.count - 1){
            let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AlphabetCollectionViewCell
            cell.startAgain.isHidden = false
            cell.startAgain.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startAgainPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.alpImage.isHidden = true
            cell.startAgain.setTitle("Start again", for: .normal)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AlphabetCollectionViewCell
            cell.alpImage.image = UIImage(named: alpImageArray[indexPath.row] + ".png")
            return cell
        }
    }

    func scrollToNextCell(){

        let cellSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        let contentOffset = myCollectionView.contentOffset
        myCollectionView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: contentOffset.x + cellSize.width, y: contentOffset.y, width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height), animated: true)
        }

    func startTimer() {

        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5,
        target: self,
        selector: #selector(scrollToNextCell),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)
    }
    @IBAction func startAgainPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        myCollectionView.resetScrollPositionToTop()
    }

}

extension UIScrollView {
    /// Sets content offset to the top.
    func resetScrollPositionToTop() {
        self.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: -contentInset.left, y: -contentInset.left)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing your Start Again button being reused after it's initially dequeued.

Since you're using the same `AlphabetCollectionViewCell` for your start button and your `alpImage cases`, you might as well dequeue it once. From there, configure the cell how you like in the if-statement. Give this a shot.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AlphabetCollectionViewCell

     if (indexPath.item >= alpImageArray.count - 1) {
         cell.alpImage.isHidden = true
         cell.startAgain.isHidden = false
         cell.startAgain.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startAgainPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
         cell.startAgain.setTitle("Start again", for: .normal)

     } else {
         cell.startAgain.isHidden = true
         cell.alpImage.isHidden = false
         cell.alpImage.image = UIImage(named: alpImageArray[indexPath.row] + ".png")
     }

     return cell
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! That was driving me crazy